# Nodejs: restore a deleted file with fs.unlink

Tags: node.js

Is possible to restore files that has been removed with `fs.unlink()` or `fs.unlinkSync()`?

Answer (score 3):

`unlink` is a system call in linux, the name comes from there. It deletes the file/folder entry or link from filesystem. It does not wipe out the file.

So is it possible to restore such files ? Yes. It is possible, but

Can you guranatee restoration ? **No**. The space occupied by file is released back to the system. So it can be written over by other processes.

Should you expect restoration ? **No**. It was not supposed to provide recycle bin like functionality. It is a low level method for programs to access filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

No.

fs.unlink will use OS dependent functionality to remove file, and this is permanent, same as `rm` in linux.

There might be very complex options that are used by data recovery companies. But there is no such functionality in node natively.

Answer (score 1):

**If you asked how to do it in Node**, the answer is: not natively.
You would have to write some C/C++ module to do this, as dealing with the disk in this way is veeery low level.

**If you asked how to do it with desktop applications**, the answer is: google it, there are lots of tools for this purpose.