# Using nodejs fs module to recovery data

Tags: node.js, fs

Is possible to create a cli tool that will recovery data from a damnaged hard disk or an usb/flash memory? I'm testing some data recovery software and I want to make my own recovery tool using nodejs. Will the `fs` module give the ability to scan for erased files?

**UPDATE**

I've done some research and I'm reading about the [N-API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/n-api.html) that is the only way to use native C/C++ libraries with node. At the moment I'm stuck to try finding a good library on github that can be used to achive this. Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832177/nodejs-restore-a-deleted-file-with-fs-unlink

Comment: @GrafiCode I've read the suggested question. The suggestion is to write a C/C++ module to read from disk using low level api. Is there any C/C++ module that can be converted to node to achive this?

Comment: `fs` will not help you here.  This is going to use OS libraries for reading/writing files.  Recovering deleted files is a much lower level operation, often specific to the type of filesystem being worked with.

Comment: @Joe since I don't have many esperience with C/C++ low level API if there is any library that can be converted to work with nodejs I will try to do the conversion and to implement it

Comment: What you're asking for is basically the guts of a file recovery product.  That's a really large problem space and probably not something you'll find in a library.  (And that's more or less off topic at SO anyway...)

Comment: @Joe I'm doing some research and maybe the best way is to use the [N-API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/n-api.html) with a C/C++ library that can read the data from a disk?